# How to get member list for an array object?

Tags: powershell

Get-Member returns an object name and member list for each type of object it contains.

```
PS C:\src\t\getlast> $a = @(1,'now')
PS C:\src\t\getlast> $a | gm

   TypeName: System.Int32
   ...
   TypeName: System.String
   ...
```

Is there a way to get the object name and member list for the array object itself? Creating an array containing an array and a different type is the only way I have found to get a list of members for an array object.

```
PS C:\src\t\getlast> $a = @(@(1),'now')
PS C:\src\t\getlast> $a.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\src\t\getlast> $a | gm

   TypeName: System.Object[]
   ...
   TypeName: System.String
   ...
```

Comment: The standard trick to prevent this unrolling behavior is to wrap it into its own array by preceding it with a comma: `,$a | gm` will get the members only of `$a` itself.

Comment: [See this article](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2018-10-15-Powershell-arrays-Everything-you-wanted-to-know/) for some nice explanations about arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Get-Member -InputObject $a
```

Essentially, feed `Get-Member` the whole object as using the pipeline pipes it element by element.